# Which mechanism allows Excel to communicate users' manipulations to outside?

Tags: python, vba, excel, vsto

[Excel provides several options for developing applications that interface with it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687829.aspx#sectionSection0).
But it seems that all these options permits of controlling Excel workbooks from outside. However, I want the other way around, precisely I would like to "listen to" users' manipulations on Excel workbooks. For example, the listener may be an add-in in Excel; when a user enter a value in a cell, the listener could catch this action, and print on the screen "enter value XXX in cell XXX". Does anyone know which mechanism is available to realise this?

**Edit 1:**
Thanks for the inputs of @Nathan_Sav and @Rik Sportel . So if I understand well, they are using VBA to listen to events and generate messages, and almost all the events can be caught.

Let me elaborate what I really want to do. Actually, I want to have an application outside Excel (e.g., written in Python or .NET), and the application can do some operations according to users' manipulations on workbooks. If the application has to read the messages generated by the VBA listener, then parse them, then do corresponding operations, I am afraid that would be slow. Is there a direct (or inner) way to let the application connected to Excel and listen to users' manipulations.

Comment: Now that I re-read the initial question: "the listener could catch this action, and print on the screen "enter value XXX in cell XXX" --> Do you mean you want messages real time when someone else edits the file?

Comment: Yes, I want real time messages... but to simplify a little bit, we can assume just one person is editing the file...

Comment: I doubt the VBA tag is in place here. VBA is slow by definition since it compiles at run time. Using the native tracking functionality you could set it to auto update changes every 5 minutes or so under the advanced options when making the workbook a shared one. Look into this https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-shared-workbook-to-collaborate-b8207fe9-a613-483f-b804-0ca4658b0c61?CorrelationId=9cd0ec96-6043-41fb-ab92-c49c3572e6e8&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US 
As for truly real time external tracking: You would indeed need a custom application / service that an addin reports to I assume.

Comment: I have read the links about tracking functionality, but I don't see how this could be connected to my external application written in Python or .NET. I could imagine that the change history (which can be displayed as a worksheet at the moment) could be useful, but still my external application needs to parse it, and even parsing a text message is easier than that, no?

Comment: Use VSTO to write a pre compiled add-in (for speed) that just sends messages to some Service written in any language. This service could then generate the pop-ups you want. However that's a wholly different question than initially asked. 

Is there any purpose in this live-tracking that can not be solved by using the native collaboration functionality (e.g. update every 5 minutes)?

Comment: Additionally, in Office 365 there is more extensive collaboration functionality. I don't really have any experience using this, so I'd advice to read up on the new functionality in the 365 suite and see if this helps you out. Never a great idea to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: "Use VSTO to write a pre compiled add-in (for speed) that just sends messages" ==> that interests me a lot. Could you please elaborate more? do you want me to open another question?

Comment: Basically write a COM addin in C# or something like that. Do some research. You basically create the same type of event logger as described in the answer and have that send messages to a service that generates pop-ups. You will need to create some interface between the two, the service will need to know how to deal with incoming messages being send from your add-in. For details I'd advice indeed a new question. I don't have an immediate answer on how to program those things available, since it this will largely depend on requirements.

Comment: when i've used this, the majority of the time its been scoped in the VBA method, and then moved to C#.NET as a VSTO addin, mine generally track a column in a worksheet in a book, so remember it can take a little longer to get new sheets/books added to this.  An XML or Text file i use in the more complex, to allow "superusers" to modify and add a book/sheet etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nathan is already pointing in the right direction.
However it could be done cleaner.

First, you're gonna need the Listener class. Place the following in a class module that you call "EventLogger"

```
Private WithEvents ExcelListener As Excel.Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set ExcelListener = Application
End Sub

Private Sub excelListener_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox Sh.Name & "!" & Target.Address & " changed into " & Target.Value
End Sub
'Hook into any other events you wish.
```

In the Workbook Module place the following in Workbook_Open()

```
Public Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set evLogger = New EventLogger
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Set evLogger = Nothing
End Sub
```

Since the Initialize event of the class already sets the application, no more is needed.

Lastly you need a regular module that has the global variable EventLogger:

```
Public evLogger As EventLogger
```

Now instead of the messagebox you could open a logfile and write every event, just append a huge string in memory and write it to a text file on close, log every single event, or whatever you want. Just expand the class to hold username, etc., be creative :)

Save the whole workbook as an add-in and install in into user's Excel. 
Enjoy!

When you only wish to track changes for a specific workbook, you can always use the native change tracker as documented here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Track-changes-in-a-shared-workbook-22aea671-cac7-4fa3-845d-eeb23725bd15

Comment: This method, gives no control over the initialisation of the listener though, so if not in list to track then dont use for example, authorised to do so etc, users who need to for example, i've used this a lot to track funds, and best to pass in the application object to a class, essentially both answers the same, apart from that :)  Hope we've been of help.

Comment: Essentially yes :) If user tracking is required however, this can still be checked in the class initialization. The EventLogger class should be abled to check who or what it needs to track imho, not the workbook. You could have a range with users to track in some external file and just check `application.username` against that during initialization. In case such stuff is needed OP should elaborate a bit on the exact scenario.

Comment: Guys, I just elaborated a little bit more in OP, what do you say?

Answer (score 1):

You can event sink the Excel application,(in an addin to control all Excel sheets), via using an class with an Excel application object, using the with events statement

so something like  (not tested as no access to vba at mo)

in a class clsExcelListner

```
private withevents excelListner as Excel.Application 

public sub initialise(ExcelApp as Excel.Application)
    set excelListner =ExcelApp
end sub
```

Then in Workbook Open

```
public cls_ExcelListner as clsExcelListner
public sub Workbook_Open()

    set cls_ExcelListner = new clsExcelListner
    cls_ExcelLister.Initialise(application)

end sub
```

In the class, you can then use the worksheet change event.  These events that will help you do what you need are already in the workbook, things like worksheet change etc, may just be best to use those, as a listner would need to take into account all documents, and say the user savesAs, then how do you check its a doc to be listened to?

Comment: So if I understand well, you are using VBA to listen to events, right? Is there a faster way to do so?

Comment: You could of course just use the native change tracker. See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Track-changes-in-a-shared-workbook-22aea671-cac7-4fa3-845d-eeb23725bd15